# Testing Service Worker and Cache in Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, service-worker, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have an app that uses Service Workers and Cache API. The cache's name used in Service Worker contains GIT revision (hash) so that with every release, new cache is used and the old one removed. This is to make 100% sure users will always get latest sources (this case is fine for intended release schedule).

I'm using Selenium Java (WebDriver) tests that run few times a day (let's say when there is a change in GIT repo) and I'd like to make sure that the worker's cache is being correctly wiped with every new GIT revision.

By default, Selenium is creating a new temporary profile directory for each browser session, which means there is always no cache when the tests start. I'd like to use cache though, my idea is (let's talk about Firefox for now):

- keep some model profile directory
- when Selenium starts Firefox, pass the model profile to the new temporary profile, e.g. `new FirefoxProfile(new File(PROFILE_MODEL))`
- this would ensure that some cache exists prior starting browser
- once tests are finished, back up the temporary profile (as it contains updated cache) and replace the (now older) `PROFILE_MODEL` with the latest profile so that next test run would use this updated cache again

The "model profile update step" at the end of test run would look like this in pseudocode

```
File modelDir = new File(PROFILE_MODEL);
// copy current model for backup
bckPath = Files.createTempDirectory("bckProfile");
Util.copy(modelDir, bckPath);

// remove the now obsolete PROFILE_MODEL
Util.deleteDirectory(modelDir);

// copy current profile to the model dir
File profileSnapshot = currentProfile.layoutOnDisk();
Util.copy(profileSnapshot.toPath(), modelPath);
```

The problem is though that the call `currentProfile.layoutOnDisk();` doesn't seem to contain any cache related information and I have no idea how to get path of the currently being used temporary profile (in Linux, typically something like `/tmp/anonymous6209009552324183685webdriver-profile`

So basically my question is, how to preserve and control browser (Firefox) cache across multiple test runs? I know it is often desired to start browser with fresh cache in tests but I think for this particular case of testing Service Workers it is quite useful to have some control over it.

Please note that I'm running the tests in CI server, so some manual solution could be quite difficult (but hey, at least it could point me to some direction...)

**Update:** I can initiate Firefox profile with

```
profile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile("test")
```

and then knowing the actual path to "test" model profile (model, not the copy created by getProfile call), I could replace all its files with the ones from calling `ProfilesIni().getProfile("test")` at the end of tests, but this does not seem to e.g. copy history of visited pages.

**Update 2:** This is how I start browser:

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxProfile sampleProfile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile("test");
caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, sampleProfile);
browser = new FirefoxDriver(caps);
```

and I can see it creates 2 profile temporary folders:

- one is created by the call `new ProfilesIni().getProfile("test")` and it won't get updated "ever" during the test
- second one is created from `FirefoxDriver.startClient` method which calls  `NewProfileExtensionConnection.start` which then calls `FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk`

Now during the tests, only the second one profile is being updated which I guess makes kind of sense. The problem is how to get the actual profile dir that is created from the capabilities...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the `FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk` method to always use the same folder for the profile:

```java
public class FirefoxProfileEx extends FirefoxProfile {

    File profileDir;

    public FirefoxProfileEx(File profileDir){
        super(profileDir);
        this.profileDir = profileDir;
    }

    public File layoutOnDisk() {
        try {
            File userPrefs = new File(profileDir, "user.js");

            installExtensions(profileDir);
            deleteLockFiles(profileDir);
            deleteExtensionsCacheIfItExists(profileDir);
            updateUserPrefs(userPrefs);
            return profileDir;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UnableToCreateProfileException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
FirefoxProfileEx profile = new FirefoxProfileEx(new File("C:\\temp\\profile"));
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: This is great. I wonder about doing the same thing with cookies. How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Known layoutOnDisk() will used to call current profile and we write or save to disk. We need to use this saved profile or dir mostly early as possible because once execution is completed then saved profile by using layoutOnDisk() is not useful. They don't work.

For more information please see [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html#layoutOnDisk--)

So for firefox only thing is just saved all cookies by using "driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies;" use these in next execution.

I hope it is prefer to use named profile instead of taking profile from directory.  [Here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows) the way to create profile

```
   ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();

   FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("myProfilewhichIsSaved");

   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

I hope IE helps by not clearing before starting. here is [link](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1997) helps you

Also you can try by chrome [profile](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but this does not work for me. I'm trying using named profile as mentioned in the update, which creates a "clone" of the named profile, it does not use the existing named profile which means any e.g. page visits will be "recorded" in the clonned profile but not the original one (it remains intact after the test). The same goes for the layoutOnDisk(), it again makes a clone of the named profile, but not the copy of the updated profile used during the test. I'll add more information to the original question. Thanks

Comment: Hi, even if you used named profile but i dont work. because once execution is done all cookies/catch will be deleted. what i meant to say is instead of calling profile from directory its good practice to use named profile. i hope you got it i meant to say

Comment: Right, but it seems like using profile set via capabilities only creates a new profile, a clone of the named profile, and the original named profile is not being "updated" anymore by actions done in tests. I need to change my setup to see how it will behave if I won't use capabilities at all.